# Referring stores defined inside svelte components?

Tags: javascript, reference, components, store, svelte

I am confused about how to refer to stores defined inside components; I can't use a store defined as a property. Supposing I have the following:

(component.svelte)

```html
<script lang="ts">
  import { writable } from 'svelte/store';
  export const prop = writable(false);
</script>
```

(App.svelte)

```html
<script lang="ts">
  import Component from './component.svelte'
  let component: Component;
</script>

<div>
  <Component bind:this={component}  />
  <!-- line below won't work -->
  {component.$prop}
</div>
```

... how can I refer to component.prop? Both syntaxes component.$prop or $component.prop won't work.
Am I required to import the stores from a separate third file in order to refer them as simple variables (i.e. $prop)?

Answer (score 0):

This is currently not possible.
What you can however do is simply bind the store prop in App.svelte instead

```html
<script>
  let prop
</script>

<Component bind:prop={prop} />
{$prop}
```

(note that you can also bind to an array `bind:prop={props[i]` if you have for instance a loop here)

an alternative way is to *destructure* your store from the component variable

```html
<script>
  let component
  $: prop = component && component.prop
</script>

<Component bind:this={component} />
{$prop}
```